# "should" could be inverted in affirmative or some type of condition sentences

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, inversion

> 1. **Should** anyone phone, tell him I'm busy.
> 2. **If** anyone phones, tell him I'm busy.

I am wondering what is the difference between those?

What is more, I am wondering as to the inversion in the first sentence has happened. Would you please show me a site so that I could study more about such a specific **inversion**?

Comment: The second sentence should be 'if anyone phone**s**'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If anyone calls, tell him I am busy.
>
> If anyone should call, tell him I am busy.

**Now what is the difference between this two?**

The first one is a normal conditional sentence, while the second one suggests that the event of calling is unlikely.

**Notes from Practical English Usage by Michael Swan -**

[image]

[image]

> Should anyone call, tell him I am busy.

We can re-write this sentence as the following -

> If anyone should call, tell him I am busy.

Note in the previous case **Should anyone call....**, we don't use **calls**.

Please visit [this link](http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/conditional-sentences-2/) for more information and examples of ***should* used at the beginning of the sentence with *if* dropped**, as you quoted in your question.

**N.B** Pam Peters in Cambridge Guide to English Usage suggests that the usage of **should** in conditional sentence is becoming less often. Conditional uses of **should** with **if** included in sentence now sound rather lofty, but the inverted **should** at the beginning of the sentence with no **if** included in that clause is still a neat way of prefacing a condition.

Answer (score 1):

The modal verb *should* certainly serves as *if* there. That said, both mean the same.

WordWeb Online Dictionary has an entry for that

> should - *Expresses a condition*

[My suggestion is to use 'call' than 'phone' in those examples].

I'm afraid whether we call those sentences as typical example of inversion. Because that's not the structure that defines a classic inversion. You asked for a link, and here it is: http://www.learn-english-today.com/lessons/lesson_contents/verbs/inversion.html