# would you show me usages of the verb should in conditional type 2 and third –

Tags: conditional-constructions

My profs. has told me the fact that we could use the verb *should* as to conditional sentences" second and third", that is, ***probable and impossible sentences:***

So, would you show me these, using the verb *should*?

Comment: In another of your question I have written an answer about the difference of meaning of normal conditional sentences with "if", and a conditional sentence with "should, but no 'if'" I have also provided a link where it says how to form a conditional sentence with "should", and how to invert the sentence, and how to omit the "if". http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/44887/3463

Comment: What @Man_From_India said. Please explain exactly what you are asking about here, and tell us why we shouldn't close this question as a duplicate of your earlier [*“should” could be inverted in affirmative or some type of condition sentences*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44271/)

Comment: as this question is around conditional sentences when it comes to use of just "should"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatically correct to use "should" instead of "would" for the pronouns I/we in conditional type 2 and type 3 sentences, but the use of "would" is more common and  that of "should" is seldom. A few examples are given below:

- If I worked harder, I would/should pass the exam. (type 2)
- If I had worked harder, I would/should have passed the exam. (type 3)
- if we had lots of money, we would/should travel round the world. (Type 2)
- If we had had lots of money, we would/should have travelled round the world (type 3)

Answer (score 2):

Though as a student I was never encouraged to classify conditional sentences into three categories as you have mentioned in your question, I still know what they are. As a student I had learned various pattern with *if*-*conditional* sentences.

Conditional sentences are classified into the following -

**1. Zero Conditional -**

> We use the zero conditional to talk about things that are always true.

**Examples -**

> If you heat water, it boils.

**2. First Conditional -**

> We use the first conditional when we talk about real and possible situations. In first conditional sentences, the structure is usually **if + present simple** and **will + infinitive**. It’s not important which clause comes first.

**Examples -**

> I’ll go shopping on the way home if I have time.

**3. Second Conditional -**

> The second conditional is used to talk about ‘unreal’ or impossible things. The structure is usually **if + past simple** and **would + infinitive**. It’s not important which clause comes first.

**Examples -**

> If I won a lot of money I’d buy a big house in the country.

**4. Third Conditional -**

> Third conditional sentences describe the past. They describe something that didn't happen. In third conditional sentences, the structure is usually **if + past perfect and would + perfect infinitive (e.g. have done)**. It’s not important which clause comes first. Notice that other modal verbs can be used instead of *‘would’* (e.g. *‘could’, ‘might’ ‘may’*)

**Examples -**

> If I’d studied harder at school I would have gone to university.

**5. Mixed Conditional -**

> In mixed conditional sentences the time in the ‘if’ clause is not the same as the time in the main clause. There can be various combinations.

**Note**

> Although many conditional sentences use if + will/would, conditional sentences can also use other words instead of ‘if’ – e.g. ‘when’ ‘as soon as’ ‘in case’ Other modal verbs can be used instead of ‘will/would’ – e.g. ‘can/could’, ‘may’ ‘might’.

I have copied all these written above from the following links.

[Link 1](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/conditionals-1)

[Link 2](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/conditionals-2)

Please visit these two links for further studies. And also it's advisable to learn the pattern of conditional sentences. Please follow a good grammar book, if you want I can suggest one for you. The link I have provided is sufficient, but leaves a lot of questions to the mind of a learner of English as a second language.

You can follow Practical English Usage by Michael Swan (From page 245 to page 253)

As for your question about the conditional with "should", please visit [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/44887/3463).