# using "should" in the second and third conditional sentences

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> If you **should** come across something weird, you would call me.( the second conditional sentence)

Could we use "should" to express a more doubtful idea in the *second* and *third* conditional sentences? would you please throw light on such an issue?

***Updated***: For clarification, I have just put some related examples that illustrate what I am strongly seeking for. You see, therefore, not only as to zero conditional sentences also the other types of conditional sentences you would use should to express more doubtfulness.

***Edited***: Is there any relation between the sentence ***R*** and ***probability*** or ***one of the following?***

R. In case you (**should**)need to me, call me.

1.If I worked harder, I would/**should** pass the exam. (type 2)

2.If I had worked harder, I would/**should** have passed the exam. (type 3)

3.if we had lots of money, we would/**should** travel round the world. (Type 2)

4.If we had had lots of money, we would/**should** have travelled round the world (type 3)

***What is more:***

I am wondering what is the difference between the following?

If we had had lots of money, we ***would***/***should*** have travelled round the world

Many thanks

Comment: I've found a related question of yours: [Should in conditional sentences](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46543/should-in-conditional-sentences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conditional sentence has two parts: the "if-part", or protasis, and "then-part", or apodosis.

In the apodosis, we use **would** to create that "conditional" feeling. So the sentence

> If we had had lots of money, we **should** have travelled round the world.

would be illogical: the protasis clearly says that we did not have money during some period in the past, but the second half of the sentence is not an apodosis, because it uses the wrong modal verb. The second half looks like a normal sentence on its own:

> We **should** have traveled around the world! (instead of doing some other things in the past, we should have traveled around the world)

This clause implies that we **had** the ability to travel around the world. It contradicts the protasis.

The same applies to your conditional 2 example:

> If I worked harder, I should pass the exam. [improbable situation in the present or future],[moral obligation]

The first part invites some apodosis with **would**. The second part just plainly states your obligation to pass the exam. But [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional),

> Occasionally, with a first person subject, the auxiliary **would** is replaced by **should** (similarly to the way will is replaced by shall). (Wikipedia says this about the apodosis of both the second and the third conditional)

So maybe we can use **should** there after all, since **I** is a first-person subject. Let a native speaker decide.

The use of **should** is usually "[deontic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality)" (what should be: used to express norms, expectations, speaker's desire) while the use of **would** is "[epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality)" (what may be).

The modal verb **should** could be sometimes used in the epistemic mood too, so we can come up with sentences such as

> If I worked harder, that **should** be surprising!

But the effect would be comical and ironical, not the usual effect with the conditional sentences. The two halves of the sentence would still look somewhat disjointed.