# conditional "If...should..." and modals

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

I am wondering whether "would" in the following sentence is correct:

> If John should lie to me, I **would** no longer talk to him.

How does the above differ from

> If John should lie to me, I **will** no longer talk to him?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Would is not acceptable in these if clauses, see [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/should), usage note.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46543/should-in-conditional-sentences

Comment: @LucianSava Your source does not say that "would" is not acceptable. It only explains it does not work in the same way as "should" does. However, your link does contain some interesting examples of *should* in the condition with future in the result: *In certain clauses, should is used for all three persons: If I (or you or he) should decide to go, we will need a larger car. If it should begin to snow, we will stay here tonight.*

Answer (score 1):

Note that **shall** and **should** used in this way are a bit old-fashioned.

Let's start of with a simple conditional,

> If John lies to me, I will no longer talk to him

The first verb is present tense and the the second is in the future tense. This is a general truth about a situation that could happen: if John **ever** lies to you, that's what will happen in the future.

> If John shall lie to me, I will no longer talk to him

This rather old-fashioned sentence means that, if at some time in the future John does lie to you, and this is a situation that could happen, you will not speak to him from that moment on.

> If John should lie to me, I would no longer talk to him

If you want to talk about a hypothetical situation, you backshift the tenses of **both** verbs: **shall** becomes **should** and **will** becomes **would**. This sentence therefore means that, in the unlikely event that John lies to you at some time in the future, you will not speak to him from that moment on.

For a hypothetical situation, you have to backshift **both** verbs. Your first sentence is therefore correct: the second sentence is not, because **should** is backshifted and **will** is not.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but even if "should" adds uncertainty to the condition, I think we can still find future (*will*) instead of conditional (*would*) in the result.

Comment: @Gustavson, can you provide links to examples of this?

Comment: Certainly. See, for example, this page in Otto Jesperpersen's *A Modern English Grammar*: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=7vW0f3VXnW4C&pg=PA333&dq=jespersen+should+conditional&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuxq3c5N3YAhUIS5AKHfUpAxIQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=jespersen%20should%20conditional&f=false . At the bottom of the page, we can read: *Papa will recover from his grief; and if he **should**, I **will** tell him.* More links and examples will follow.

Comment: In *English Grammar: A University Course* by Angela Downing (https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=vdrfBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA265&dq=%22if+you+should%22+conditional&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGreDU5t3YAhVMgJAKHVIGCxQQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22if%20you%20should%22%20conditional&f=false) we can find in example (18) that "should" can combine with "can" (not necessarily with "could"): ***Should** you decide to come to the concert, we **can** meet at the concert hall.*

Comment: @Gustavson: I do not accept an example sentence in a grammar book written by a Danish guy born in 1860 as an example of actual current usage.

Comment: "We **can** go to the beach on Sunday" could be interpreted as a statement of fact or a possibility. **will** has no such ambiguity.

Comment: You don't accept Otto Jespersen as an authority in English grammar? Discussion closed.

Comment: In case you want to open your eyes, here's some more evidence: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=kn8VAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA46&dq=%22if+he+should%22+conditional&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw8Iy66N3YAhUJFZAKHUKoBwUQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22if%20he%20should%22%20conditional&f=false

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Jespersen's example (apart from the _should_ construction being rather old fashioned now). But the _should_ can correspond to two different modern forms: _If he recovers, I will tell him_ and _If he recovered I would tell him_. The first implies that recovery is more likely than the second.