# Should with 2nd and 3rd conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

Here is a link which I came across on this site.
[Should in conditional sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46543/should-in-conditional-sentences)

It prohibits the usage of 'should' with type 2 and type 3. There are multiple sources which concur with this rule and multiple credible sources which include 'should' with type 2 and type 3.

I don't understand why 'should' cannot be used with the below type 2 examples:

a. If **he were to be** late again, he **should (or would have to)** meet me before entering the class.

b. If you met (were to meet) John, you **should** remind him about the money he owes me.

I would also appreciate your thoughts on the type 3 example:
c. If **you had stayed** with a Mexican friend for years in Dallas, you **should have** studied Spanish.

Comment: ***should*** in (a) is fine, but I suggest you avoid the subjunctive form wherever possible: *If he **is** late again, he **should** see me upon arrival.* Note that (b) is invalid with Past Tense ***met*** - that would be like changing (a) to *If he **was** late again, he'd be suspended* (or worse, *...he'll be suspended*). That Simple Past after ***if*** does sometimes occur in "uneducated" speech, but you should certainly avoid it if you want to pass exams!

Comment: ...I'm not convinced English actually *has* a short, succinct way of referring to *how someone should have acted* or *what they should have done* IF some hypothetical situation had arisen ***in the past (but it DIDN'T),*** as in your "should have studied Spanish" example. In practice, the words you've written imply the speaker doesn't *know* whether you met the "precondition" (staying with a friend for years), but he's asserting that ***if in fact you did***, he takes it for granted you ***will** have studied Spanish*.

Comment: I don't think much of "numbered conditionals" anyway (there are too many variations to assign unique numbers to all possibilities). But [*The type 3 conditional refers to an impossible condition in the past and its probable result in the past,*](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/type-3-conditional/), which is ***not*** the meaning of your final example in "standard" English today (we use *If that **had** been true, this **would** be true*, not ***should***). So there you are - your "type 3" is an exotic rare "obligation, duty" context that hasn't been assigned a number!

Answer (score 3):

'should' is possible in all conditionals (although conditionals are a poor point of view) but pay attention to the meaning. According to *Practical English Usage*:

> Should can be used to express the deduction or conclusion that something is probable now or in the future: it is expected, normal or logical.
>
> We do not normally use should + infinitive to talk about the past.
>
> However, we can use should have / ought to have + past participle to make guesses or draw conclusions about things which are not certain to have happened.
>
> We can also use this structure to talk about actions which we expect to have been completed by now or at a future time.