# "I would never have thought so had you not told me that" without "if"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

Should I say this sentence without "if"? why or why not?

> "I would never have thought so {if} you had  not told me that"

or

> "I would never have thought so had you not told me that" without

The context:
I meet someone, and when I ask her where is she from, she told me from Sweden. She didn't look like someone from Sweden...  So my response to her thing was as mention above.

Comment: Both sentences works to my ear as I mentally add the if without effort.

Comment: Similar http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44271/should-could-be-inverted-in-affirmative-or-some-type-of-condition-sentences/44887#44887

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't find the similarity to my question in your link. In my question there is using of "if" in one of the correct versions .

Answer (score 1):

**Inversion** for conditionals is used for a more formal style.
When omitting the **if** clause, you apply inversion in the beginning of the sentence.

> Had you not told me that, I would never have thought so.